# How to get JSON.stringify into PHP with json_decode without AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, json, form-submit

Say, I have something like this

```
function submitform() {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "userdata": $('#user_data').val()
    })
    $('<input type="hidden" name="json"/>').val(data).appendTo('#myform');
    $("#myform").submit();
}
```

Now on the Server side, I've tried:

```
json_decode($_POST['json']);
json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['json']), true);
```

All of these return `NULL` value when I do a `var_dump` on the page.

I am not submitting the form via ajax, and I do not want to use `application/json` to submit the form because there are other fields in the form that need to be submitted the normal form submission way.

How can I do this??  Just need to send json to php on form submission.

Comment: Under what event are you calling `submitform()`? What's the `action` attribute set to on the `form` element? Also note that your method of appending the user_id to the URL is really not secure in any way.

Comment: What is the `method` used on your form? I know, it could be obvious, but if its not filled in you will need to look inside `$_GET`...

Comment: `method="post"` on form.

Comment: Console.log `data` before you submit.  Does it have a value?

Comment: Yes, it is the JSON string data.  If I do `$_POST['json']` I get the string data also, from the PHP end.  `json_decode` is not working though.

Comment: try to var_dump($_POST) to see if it hits the php page

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use a PHP that magic-quotes your POST variables?  Please let us see the actual string your php script receives...  (Write it into a file so you see every single character - or htmlspecialchars() it, if that fits you better)

Comment: Yes, it hits the PHP page.  I can do `$_POST['json']` and get the string data.

Comment: Actually, the json object is a bit different, but the string returned from php `$_POST` input name field is this:  `string(249) "[{\"title\":\"Silane Adhesion Promoters:\",\"products\":[\"953\",\"11870\",\"2088\"]},{\"title\":\"Functional Silicones for Silicone Sealants:\",\"products\":[\"8923\",\"9640\",\"9495\"]},{\"title\":\"Catalysts:\",\"products\":[\"4654\",\"10034\"]}]"`

Comment: `json_decode` is returning `NULL` value however.  Why?

Comment: There you go.  That's magic quotes working. Do a stripslashes() and it will work.

Comment: Doesn't make sense from code that is shown

Comment: that's not magic quotes, var_dump adds the quotes (because it displays string "whatever")

Comment: `stripslashes()` did the trick, thanks very much guys!

Comment: omg :) I'm stupid :)

Comment: Okay, let me put it in answer

Comment: Thank you!  Let me upvote the question in return :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the magic quotes screw up your JSON string and PHP doesn't recognize it anymore.  Use **stripslashes()** before you hand it over to **json_decode()**:

```
$a = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']));
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for magic quotes or will `stripslashes()` in order to know whether to use it or not, or will it work either way?

Comment: Is it needed to be known you think?  Before doing `stripslashes`?  Like I wouldn't want this script to get screwed up on different server with different magic quotes set.

Comment: Normally you can do a strip() safely every time.  But if your string contains intentional backslashes (? does it? very unlikely), stripslashes() will remove them.  Which is a mistake, of course.  Also, consider base64 if you want to receive EVERYTHING without all the mess :)